# Dynamic fields not being submitted (jQuery, web2py)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, web2py

I'm writing an app using web2py and I'm currently trying to make a form where the user can add/remove additional fields on the fly. I've got this working by using jQuery to add the addition fields to the DOM but the problem is only the hardcoded fields are being submitted (I am dumping form.vars at the top of the page to check). I have made sure the dynamic fields have unique names and I've been scouring the html for errors but have come up with nothing.

Here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var wrapper = $("#formwrapper");
    var addbutton = $("#addfield");
    var removebutton = $('#removefield');

    var x = 2;

    $(addbutton).click(function(){

        $(wrapper).append(
            "<div id='extrareward"+ x +"'><h3>Reward " + x + "</h3>" +
            "<label>Minimum amount to get reward:  </label>" +
            "<input name='min"+ x +"' type='text'><br>" +
            "<label>Reward Description:  </label>" +
            "<textarea name='reward"+ x +"' rows='10' cols='40'></textarea></div>"
        );

        x++;
    });

    $(removebutton).click(function(){
        if (x > 2) {
            x--;
            var id = '#extrareward' + x;
            $(id).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the html form from the page source with one static and one dynamic block:

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div id="formwrapper">
        <label>Minimum amount to get reward:  </label>
        <input name="min1" type="text" value=""><br>
        <label>Reward description:  </label>
        <textarea cols="40" name="reward1" rows="10"></textarea><br>
        <div id="extrareward2">
            <h3>Reward 2</h3>
            <label>Minimum amount to get reward:  </label>
            <input name="min2" type="text"><br>
            <label>Reward Description:  </label>
            <textarea name="reward2"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input id="submitbutton" type="submit">

    <div style="display:none;">
        <input name="_formkey" type="hidden" value="1e315a07-a035-4858-822c-614c962ebb98">
        <input name="_formname" type="hidden" value="default">
    </div>
</form>
```

and finally here is the code for the controller:

```
@auth.requires_login()    
def create2():

    form = FORM(DIV(LABEL('Minimum amount to get reward:  '), INPUT(_name='min1', _type='text'), BR(),
                    LABEL('Reward description:  '), TEXTAREA(_name='reward1'), BR(),
                    _id='formwrapper'),
                INPUT(_id='submitbutton', _type='submit'))

    if form.process(keepvalues=True).accepted:
        session.flash = 'form accepted'

    else:
        session.flash = 'form rejected'

    return dict(loginform=auth.login(),
                rewardtiersform=form)
```

Might be that I'm just missing a silly error somewhere but I've been scratching my head for too long in this. Help much appreciated!

Comment: can you put the names of the inputs as arrays? change "reward" into "reward[]" and see what happens

Comment: Please show the controller code (i.e., where you define the server side form object). Note, you must define the form object with all fields that it will process -- it will ignore fields sent from the client that are not defined on the server. You will find all the values in `request.post_vars`, but only the ones defined in the form object will be processed by the form.

Comment: @ chepe263 I gave it a shot but still having the same issue, sorry

Comment: Aha, Anthony you hit the nail on the head. So I will just use request.post_vars instead. Thanks very much!